# How to show back date and future date content on list view android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-activity, android-sqlite

I am showing content from database of today's date in list view and I want to add functionality that on clicking back date button the content of previous date is shown.But it shows data of both dates. It is adding it to same list view. How to resolve it ?

### This is prev date function

```
prevMonth.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
                formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());

                Log.v("PREVIOUS DATE : ", formattedDate);
                currentDate.setText(formattedDate);
                new getfooditems().execute();//calling method of different class which displays the data in the list
                //ListView lv = getListView();
            }
        });
```

### getfooditems

```
class getfooditems extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private String foodname;
        private String totalcalorie;
        private String fat;
        private String carbohydrate;
        private String protein;
        private String foodtype;
        private String created_at;

        //private String category;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            CalorieDMealsDiaryActivity.this.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            DatabaseHandler helper = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
            SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
            String query = "SELECT foodname,foodtype,totalcalorie,fat,carbohydrate,protein,created_at from fooditem WHERE name = ('"+fname+"') AND created_at = ('"+formattedDate+"')";

            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> parametres = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            // there is some record available in the cursor 
            if (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                    foodname = cursor.getString(0);
                    System.out.println("value of foodname in meals diary activity" + foodname);
                    foodtype = cursor.getString(1);
                    System.out.println("meals diary foodtype" + foodtype);
                    totalcalorie= cursor.getString(2);
                    fat = cursor.getString(3);
                    carbohydrate = cursor.getString(4);
                    protein = cursor.getString(5);
                    created_at = cursor.getString(6);
                    System.out.println("value of totalcalorie in meals diary activity " + totalcalorie);
                    Log.e("foodtype" , foodtype);



                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> breakfastmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    HashMap<String, String> lunchmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    HashMap<String, String> dinnermap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    HashMap<String, String> snacksmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    if(foodtype.equals("Breakfast")){
                        breakfastmap.put(TAG_FOODNAME, foodname);
                        Log.e("foodname","foodname:" + foodname);
                        breakfastmap.put(TAG_TOTALCALORIE, totalcalorie);
                        Log.e("totalcalorie","totalcalorie:" + totalcalorie);
                        breakfastmap.put(TAG_FAT, fat);
                        Log.e("fat","fat:" + fat);
                        breakfastmap.put(TAG_CARBOHYDRATE, carbohydrate);
                        Log.e("carbohydrate","carbohydrate:" + carbohydrate);
                        breakfastmap.put(TAG_PROTEIN, protein);
                        Log.e("protein","protein:" + protein);
                        breakfastmap.put(TAG_CREATED_AT, created_at);
                        Log.e("created_at","created_at:" + created_at);


                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        breakfastitems.add(breakfastmap);
                        cursor.moveToNext();

                    }
                    else if(foodtype.equals("Lunch")){
                        lunchmap.put(TAG_FOODNAME, foodname);
                        Log.e("foodname","foodname:" + foodname);
                        lunchmap.put(TAG_TOTALCALORIE, totalcalorie);
                        Log.e("totalcalorie","totalcalorie:" + totalcalorie);
                        lunchmap.put(TAG_FAT, fat);
                        Log.e("fat","fat:" + fat);
                        lunchmap.put(TAG_CARBOHYDRATE, carbohydrate);
                        Log.e("carbohydrate","carbohydrate:" + carbohydrate);
                        lunchmap.put(TAG_PROTEIN, protein);
                        Log.e("protein","protein:" + protein);
                        lunchmap.put(TAG_CREATED_AT, created_at);
                        Log.e("created_at","created_at:" + created_at);


                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        lunchitems.add(lunchmap);
                        cursor.moveToNext();
                    }
                    else if(foodtype.equals("Dinner")){
                        dinnermap.put(TAG_FOODNAME, foodname);
                        Log.e("foodname","foodname:" + foodname);
                        dinnermap.put(TAG_TOTALCALORIE, totalcalorie);
                        Log.e("totalcalorie","totalcalorie:" + totalcalorie);
                        dinnermap.put(TAG_FAT, fat);
                        Log.e("fat","fat:" + fat);
                        dinnermap.put(TAG_CARBOHYDRATE, carbohydrate);
                        Log.e("carbohydrate","carbohydrate:" + carbohydrate);
                        dinnermap.put(TAG_PROTEIN, protein);
                        Log.e("protein","protein:" + protein);
                        dinnermap.put(TAG_CREATED_AT, created_at);
                        Log.e("created_at","created_at:" + created_at);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        dinneritems.add(dinnermap);
                        cursor.moveToNext();
                    }
                    else if(foodtype.equals("Snacks")){
                        snacksmap.put(TAG_FOODNAME, foodname);
                        Log.e("foodname","foodname:" + foodname);
                        snacksmap.put(TAG_TOTALCALORIE, totalcalorie);
                        Log.e("totalcalorie","totalcalorie:" + totalcalorie);
                        snacksmap.put(TAG_FAT, fat);
                        Log.e("fat","fat:" + fat);
                        snacksmap.put(TAG_CARBOHYDRATE, carbohydrate);
                        Log.e("carbohydrate","carbohydrate:" + carbohydrate);
                        snacksmap.put(TAG_PROTEIN, protein);
                        Log.e("protein","protein:" + protein);
                        snacksmap.put(TAG_CREATED_AT, created_at);
                        Log.e("created_at","created_at:" + created_at);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        snacksitems.add(snacksmap);
                        cursor.moveToNext();
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Nonononono");
                    }
                }
            }

            // there is some record available in the cursor 

            cursor.close();

            return query;   

        }




        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            CalorieDMealsDiaryActivity.this
            .setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    System.out.println("foodtype in run" + foodtype);

                    System.out.println("I am inside run() hahahaha");
                    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            CalorieDMealsDiaryActivity.this, breakfastitems,
                            R.layout.list_xml, new String[] {TAG_FOODNAME ,TAG_TOTALCALORIE,TAG_FAT,TAG_CARBOHYDRATE,TAG_PROTEIN}, new int[] { 
                                    R.id.name,R.id.uid, R.id.fatout,R.id.carbsout,R.id.proteinsout });

                    adapterlunch = new SimpleAdapter(
                            CalorieDMealsDiaryActivity.this, lunchitems,
                            R.layout.list_lunch_xml, new String[] {TAG_FOODNAME ,TAG_TOTALCALORIE,TAG_FAT,TAG_CARBOHYDRATE,TAG_PROTEIN}, new int[] { 
                                    R.id.name,R.id.uid, R.id.fatout,R.id.carbsout,R.id.proteinsout });

                    adapterdinner = new SimpleAdapter(
                            CalorieDMealsDiaryActivity.this, dinneritems,
                            R.layout.list_dinner_xml, new String[] {TAG_FOODNAME ,TAG_TOTALCALORIE,TAG_FAT,TAG_CARBOHYDRATE,TAG_PROTEIN}, new int[] { 
                                    R.id.name,R.id.uid, R.id.fatout,R.id.carbsout,R.id.proteinsout });

                    adaptersnacks = new SimpleAdapter(
                            CalorieDMealsDiaryActivity.this, snacksitems,
                            R.layout.list_snacks_xml, new String[] {TAG_FOODNAME ,TAG_TOTALCALORIE,TAG_FAT,TAG_CARBOHYDRATE,TAG_PROTEIN}, new int[] { 
                                    R.id.name,R.id.uid, R.id.fatout,R.id.carbsout,R.id.proteinsout });

                    listbreakfast.setAdapter(adapter);
                    listlunch.setAdapter(adapterlunch);
                    listdinner.setAdapter(adapterdinner);
                    listsnacks.setAdapter(adaptersnacks);


                }
            });
        }



    }
```

Comment: If breakfastitems, lunchitems, dinneritems, snacksitems are array list then you need to clear them in onPreExecute method.

Comment: Also your onPostExecute already runs on main thread so no need to call runOnUiThread. In addition to this, initialize your adapters in onCreate only once and when you need to update in onPostExecute do list.clear(); list.addAll(items); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

You did so much complicated things I think to get current or previous date.

Simply you can do to get prev date.

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentDate = cal.get(Calendar.DATE) -1;//prev date , remove -1 for current date.
```

SimpleDateFormate we are using when we need to format the date in month year date and all...

Do this to reload listview....
asynch task declare all listview above

onprepare
      than initialize all list in the prepare

in doinbackground clear all list before use

and than do adapting in post....

hope you take it solution

Comment: Date is changing and data is also coming but with data which already have been loaded

Comment: it seems you are not clearing all data .... 
clear all data and reload asynch than do notifyDataSetChanged()....

Comment: where should i add that ?

Comment: after adapting listview

Answer (score 0):

Clear all the previous items from all the arraylist before reading new record from database like:

```
    breakfastitems.clear();
    lunchitems.clear();
    dinneritems.clear();
    snacksitems.clear();
```

It will solve your problem

Comment: Where should i add these lines?

Comment: Call before Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);